# Wordpress remove external stylesheet

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress theme en-queues below styles. But, I want to remove the second stylesheet as I don't require it.

I tried removing the wp_enqueue_style statement without success. My page losses all the styles when I do so.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'open-sans-google-font', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'source-code-pro-google-font', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro' );
```

Comment: your target is to remove this font: `wp_enqueue_style( 'source-code-pro-google-font', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro' ); ?`

Comment: If you're using a pre-made theme, I would suggest making a child theme so that you are not altering your theme's files directly(which will mess everything up if you ever need to update your theme). Once you've created your child theme you should be using [wp_dequeue_style](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style) for this.

Comment: I tried wp_dequeue_style right after the enqueue function in header.php. But it's not removing.